# modify regular expression to ignore underscores after question marks

Tags: regex

```
(.[^_]+)
```

Matches correctly when there is no underscore, how can I modify this regex to match when there is no underscore only before a question mark ?

ie. ignore any underscores after ?

Comment: Is this supposed to be a full pattern or only a fragment? Do you mean that it ignores underscores marks **DIRECTLY AFTER** a question mark, or simply all underscores after the first question mark in the string?

Comment: ignore all underscores after question mark

Comment: Now that was... incredibly useless! O_O

Comment: That's still meaningless. Allow or disallow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only allow underscores after the question mark:

`(.[^_]*(\?.*)?)`

Answer (score 0):

`.[^_]*?\?.*`

Anything except for underscore zero or more times, lazy quantifier (the shortest match), followed by a question mark. Another option:

`.[^_\?]*\?.*`

Answer (score 0):

Put the question mark itself into your negated character class:

```
(.[^_?]+)
```

This will match all characters until it’s either an underscore or a question mark.